# how payment can be deposited to merchants acc who(merchants) gave permissions to my application

Tags: spring-boot, paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro, paypal-here

For account of US based.

Currently  merchants gave  permission to my application to accept payment on their behalf to accept payments. but issue is i am always getting payment in my account not in registered merchant accounts.

i have used merchant onboarding APIs : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/

https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize
gettting refresh token for merchant using below api
/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice
.field("grant_type", "refresh_token")
.field("refresh_token", refreshToken)

can someone please help me to solve this ? or any other solution then please give me some details about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you referenced is for PayPal Here, which is a PayPal application. It is probably not related to what you want to be doing.

---

With [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), payments can be directed to a different destination account by including a [`payee` object](https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#definition-payee) in the purchase_units of the request.

Example using an email_address:

```js
    {
      intent: 'CAPTURE',
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          currency_code: 'USD',
          value: '220.00'
        },
        payee: {
          email_address: 'receiveraccount@emaildomain.com'
        }
      }]
    }
```

If you used the correct [Multiparty (not PayPal Here) onboarding API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/), you may have their merchant_id. The merchant_id is more permanent than the email_address (cannot be changed on the PayPal account), so use that instead.

The merchant id can also be included in the JS SDK line as `merchant-id` [when loading the script](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#merchant-id), which helps determine payment method eligibility; but you still need to include the `payee` object in the request as well, and these two ids must match.

Comment: Thanks for your help as your solution worked for me while creating an order. but i can't figure out how to change while updating order i am doing as below
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount,payee",
        "value": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "5.00",
            "payee": {
                "merchant_id":"5MPBDAU7HZVND"
            }
        }
    }
]

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch `payee/email_address` can be patched, merchant_id cannot